# In app purchase is not working after release but it was working in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

Reject from Apple for In APP Purchase

During development in app purchase auto-renewing subscription, I've created test accounts which are able to obtain the product of the in app purchase as well as actually purchasing it without an issue. I've submitted the version to the testFlight Beta and testing in app purchase as well as purchasing it with test accounts works well at sandbox mode environment. However after submitted to the IOS version app to the Apple review, the version of the app can't even retrieve the product, and nothing shows up when I press the button to send the purchase request.

IAP is attached to the binary and IAP  is approved with the binary that i submit. But its not displaying in the production. In sandbox its listing fine.

Please tell me how you solved this problem?
Or is this factor not decisive and the application will not be rejected for this reason?